# Batch upload of images in Wikia

Tags: upload, wikia

I want to upload a bunch of pictures (PNG, approx. one thousand) to Wikia (if I understand it correctly it runs MediaWiki under the hood).

Is there a way to just select a directory on my PC, select a category it should be put to and let it automatically upload all the files?

I tried [MultiUploader](http://dev.wikia.com/wiki/MultiUploader), but it throws a bunch of errors and even if it was working I don't know how to add all those newly uploaded images to one category.

Comment: Is it your server? Do you have an FTP account to login to manage it?

Comment: No, it's not my server and I don't think they provide FTP access :( - [wikia](http://www.wikia.com/About_Us).

Comment: Can you use the [API](http://api.wikia.com/wiki/Documentation) to [upload](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Upload)?

Comment: I was kinda hoping that there is some multi-upload tool already done, but only ones I found were server-side extensions.

Answer (score 2):

There are several good options using the MediaWiki web API.

With a graphical interface: use [VicuñaUploader](https://github.com/yarl/vicuna/wiki/Quick-start). Not much to say, basically just install it and enter your wiki URL, directory. The rest will be obvious.

From the command line, use [pywikibot's upload.py](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Pywikibot/upload.py). Something like:

```
for image in $(ls); do ... upload.py -family:wikia -lang:mywiki -filename:$image -noverify; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `special:upload` with [MultiUpload](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiUpload), but [you are limited to 10 at a time](http://community.wikia.com/wiki/Help%3aMultiple_uploads) due to possible abuse.

Your link, [MultiUploader](http://dev.wikia.com/wiki/MultiUploader) can only be used by [Autoconfirmed Users](http://community.wikia.com/wiki/Help%3aUser_access_levels)

Comment: MultiUpload: Uploading ~1k images in groups of 10 and selecting it every time by hand is not an option. MultiUploader: I'm in autoconfirmed group, but the program is buggy - sometimes it does not upload a file even though it said it did, after some number of uploads (4?) it starts to popup message box with error every time next file is being uploaded. I wanted an automatic way of uploading = select folder, click upload button and let it do its work. Clicking thousand times every few seconds are pretty far from automatic...